# PHP Laravel 5.4 InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.4

I am trying to validate my form using the validate request controller so far i have:

```
public function register_check(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username'=> 'required|min:6|max:20',   
            'email'=> 'required|unique',
            'password'=> 'required|min:6|max:30',
            'repeat_password'=>'required|same:password'
        ]);
    }
```

I am new to laravel.

Comment: Validation rule unique requires at least 1 parameters.

Comment: sorry i forgot to include

Answer (score 2):

the 'email' part, try using 'required|unique:users , the users is your users table name.